# Angular 6 - Kendo UI Grid cell template

Tags: angular, html5-canvas, kendo-grid, angular6

I'm trying to place a `<canvas>` element within a `kendoGridCellTemplate` in Angular 6. However, I'm getting an error: `"Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined"` .

If I test it by placing the `<canvas>` above the grid, I can see it works. However, inside the `<ng-template>`  it doesn't.

I guess the main question is: can this be done ? If so, what am I doing wrong.

```js
export class CustomerListComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit{

  ...
 @ViewChild("customerInitials") customerInitials;
   ...

   constructor() {  }
   
   ...
   
   drawInitials () {
 let colours = ["#1abc9c", "#2ecc71", "#3498db", "#9b59b6", "#34495e", "#16a085", "#27ae60", "#2980b9", "#8e44ad", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#e67e22", "#e74c3c", "#95a5a6", "#f39c12", "#d35400", "#c0392b", "#bdc3c7", "#7f8c8d"];

 let name = "Bob Mazzo";
    let nameSplit = name.split(" ");
    let initials = nameSplit[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + nameSplit[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase(); 

    let charIndex = initials.charCodeAt(0) - 65;
    let colourIndex = charIndex % 19;

    // GET CANVAS HERE !
   this.canvas = this.customerInitials.nativeElement;
   this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

        
    let canvasWidth = this.canvas.width;
    let canvasHeight = this.canvas.height;
    let canvasCssWidth = canvasWidth;
    let canvasCssHeight = canvasHeight;

    if (window.devicePixelRatio) {    
    this.canvas.width = canvasWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
    this.canvas.height = canvasHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;
    this.canvas.style.width =  canvasCssWidth;
    this.canvas.style.height = canvasCssHeight;
    this.context.scale(window.devicePixelRatio, window.devicePixelRatio);
    }

    this.context.fillStyle = colours[colourIndex];
    this.context.fillRect (0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    this.context.font = "16px Arial";
    this.context.textAlign = "center";
    this.context.fillStyle = "#FFF";
    this.context.fillText(initials, canvasCssWidth / 2, canvasCssHeight / 1.5);
  }

}
```

```html
<kendo-grid-column>
 <ng-template kendoHeaderTemplate let-column></ng-template>
 <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>  
  {{ drawInitials() }}
  <canvas #customerInitials id="user-icon" width="35" height="35" ></canvas>
 </ng-template>    
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution forgoes the `canvas` element, and just uses a `circle` class and a `span` instead:

```js
getCustomerInitials(dataItem) {
 let first = dataItem.FirstName !== undefined ? dataItem.FirstName[0].toUpperCase() : '';
 let last = dataItem.LastName !== undefined ? dataItem.LastName[0].toUpperCase() : '';
 return first + last;
    
  }
```

```html
<kendo-grid-column>
 <ng-template kendoHeaderTemplate let-column></ng-template>
 
 <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
  <a>
   <i class="circle" style="background: antiquewhite; display: inline-flex; height: 30px; width: 30px;
          border-radius: 50%; border: white; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">      
    <span style="margin: 6px 0 0 5px; color: #000;font: 14px Arial;">
     {{ getCustomerInitials(dataItem) }}
    </span>
   </i>      
  </a>
 </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```